# Why is my added datatable rows disappearing from the table as soon as my foreach loop closes?

Tags: c#, dynamic, foreach, datatable

I am adding rows dynamically, as well as columns, into a datatable. The rows add as far as I can see, but as soon as I run the code nothing appears. It's like it's refreshing the table once the foreach loop finishes? Rookie question. Sorry.

```
        summaryTable.Columns.Add("StationName", typeof(string));
        summaryTable.Columns.Add("DepartmentCode", typeof(string));
        var row = summaryTable.NewRow();

        foreach (var item in issuesByClass)
        {
            row.SetField("StationName", item.StationName);
            row.SetField("DepartmentCode", item.DepartmentCode);

            foreach (var itemClass in item.Lookup)
            {
                if (!itemClassLookup.ContainsKey(itemClass.Key)) continue;

                var itemClassValue = itemClassLookup[itemClass.Key];
                // Ensure column hasn't been added before
                if (!summaryTable.Columns.Contains(itemClassValue))
                {
                    summaryTable.Columns.Add(itemClassValue, typeof(decimal));
                }
                row.SetField(itemClassValue, itemClass.Sum());
            }

            if (!summaryTable.Columns.Contains("GrandTotal"))
            {
                summaryTable.Columns.Add("GrandTotal", typeof(decimal));
            }
            row.SetField("GrandTotal", item.GrandTotal);
        }
        return summaryTable;
```

Small windows form app example:

```
public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Test();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        var subs = new[] { "Sub 1", "Sub 2", "Sub 3" };
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (var sub in subs)
        {
            if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Subs"))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("Subs");
            }
            row.SetField("Subs", sub);
        }

        dt.Columns.Add("Test");
        row.SetField("Test", 1M);

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NewRow()` **doesn't add the row**. You need to do that manually at the bottom of the loop via `.Rows.Add(row)`. You should also probably create the `NewRow()` per iteration.

```
    foreach (var item in issuesByClass)
    {
        var row = summaryTable.NewRow();

        // ...

        summaryTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Comment: I might be doing it wrong, but if I create the NewRow() per iteration, I get a very busted results table back. The data is strewn around. It literally adds a new row for everything, where it should just add the data onto the row, by class. Does my explanation make sense? I see you bolded the doesn't add row bit. I know it's a dumb question. I've never done this before, still learning, trying my best.

Comment: @JudithJoubert I may have missed a subtlety in your code, but: however many rows you intended to add is usually the number of times you should be calling `.NewRow()` and `.Rows.Add()`. If you only intended to add 1 row despite the loop, then yes: you would only call `.NewRow()` and `.Rows.Add()` once

Comment: It works now. I can't add the final code since it's too many characters. Basically I added the columns before adding the rows so that the schema is already set, then I started adding the rows, implementing the `.NewRow()` and `Rows.Add()` per loop iteration, as per your second comment @MarkGravell - thank you, I really appreciate your assistance.